# React service-worker being permanently cached in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker, browser-cache

In Chrome, my react service-worker (created with CRA) is being cached permanently and serving an old build. Hard reload doesn't change anything. If I go in the dev tools and manually select bypass for network that fixes the problem, but obviously this is not a solution that will work for clients. Our app is being served with Apache. Basically, I'm wondering the best way to specify `no-cache` in this situation?

I have seen posts that suggest the use of `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control">` tags in index.html, but I have also read that it's preferable to specify `Cache-control: no-cache` in the Apache confs -- so any definitive answer regarding best practices would be welcome. I have also tried to simply `unregister()` the service worker to no avail.

```
// I also tried tweaking my SW configs here
// registerServiceWorker.js

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl, {
      updateViaCache: "none" // <-- optional param
    }
```

Despite what I have tried, anyone who has visited the old site on Chrome is "stuck" with that old build currently.

Answer (score 0):

From a guy I follow on Twitter,

> I also recommend opening up src/index.js and removing the call to registerServiceWorker() at the bottom, since it can cause some confusing caching issues (like preventing you from accessing the API endpoints in a browser after you load the React app once).

[In this blog post](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/)

Comment: Yes, I have already removed that line. The problem is that the browser is never even made aware that changes to the SW configs occurred as the cached SW intercepts everything....

Comment: I have that same problem. Did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, with your app open go to the Aplication tab and click on service workers in the left navigation. From there you can stop the worker if your app didn't stop it properly or unregister it if you are no longer using it.

[image]